react native with Expo Android Problem with react-native-signature-canvas
i tried to implement a signature for my react native app that i am running on Expo Android but i got an Error
this is the error :
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method WebViewMessageHandler11.onMessage(). Module has not been registered as callable. Bridgeless Mode: false. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 12): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, HMRClient, AppRegistry, RCTEventEmitter, RNCWebViewMessagingModule.
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
this is my code :
import SignatureScreen from "react-native-signature-canvas";
import { useRef } from "react";
const Sign = ({ text, onOK }) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  // Called after ref.current.readSignature() reads a non-empty base64 string
  const handleOK = (signature) => {
    console.log(signature);
    onOK(signature); // Callback from Component props
  };

  // Called after ref.current.readSignature() reads an empty string
  const handleEmpty = () => {
    console.log("Empty");
  };

  // Called after ref.current.clearSignature()
  const handleClear = () => {
    console.log("clear success!");
  };

  // Called after end of stroke
  const handleEnd = () => {
    ref.current.readSignature();
  };

  // Called after ref.current.getData()
  const handleData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <SignatureScreen
      ref={ref}
      onEnd={handleEnd}
      onOK={handleOK}
      onEmpty={handleEmpty}
      onClear={handleClear}
      onGetData={handleData}
      autoClear={true}
      descriptionText={text}
    />
  );
};

export default Sign;

I tried this library and it didn't work for me

Because react-native-signature-canvas relays on react-native-webview  you should add it to your expo dependencies https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/webview/

how to add webview

@HaythemKhiari check the link I posted in answer:
npx expo install react-native-webview
